# How to access a value within a .csv file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to access a value within a .csv file. If the value is 200 or above i would like to append the whole line to a list. I keep getting an error that says index out of range at the `if(line[2] >= str(200)):` line. Any help with this error would be greatly appreciated.

```
import csv
fields=[]
rows=[]
def readFile():
    with open('employee-logins.csv','r') as file:
        data=csv.reader(file)
        fields=next(data)
        for line in data:
            if(line[2] >= str(200)):
                rows.append(line)
    file.close()
readFile()
```

Here is the data for the .csv file. If the number of logins for a line is 200 or above, i would like to append it to the list.

```
['First;Last;Logins;IP_Address']
['Codie;Junifer;244;218.57.222.107']
['Dale;Cullingford;177;199.21.64.239']
['Dasie;Rodolf;171;45.235.38.213']
```

Comment: There is nothing at `line[2]`, try using `print(line)` after `for line in data`, and checking what you have there.

Comment: Also, `str()` simply returns the argument as a string. So in this case, it will return `"200"`. I think what you want is to check the length of the line: `len(line) >= 200`

Comment: can you also add csv data to question

Comment: Sorry i should have been a bit more clear in the question. I want to see if the value of the data in the ```[2]``` column is above 200 rather than the length.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
import csv
fields=[]
rows=[]
def readFile():
    with open('employee-logins.csv','r') as file:
        data=csv.reader(file)
        fields=next(data)
        for line in data:
            if(int(line.split(',')[2]) >= 200):  #assumin values are saperated using , if not replace it with ;
                rows.append(line)
    file.close()
readFile()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want to compare integers, i.e., `int(line[2]) >= 200`.

```py
import csv

lines = [
    'First;Last;Logins;IP_Address',
    'Codie;Junifer;244;218.57.222.107',
    'Dale;Cullingford;177;199.21.64.239',
    'Dasie;Rodolf;171;45.235.38.213',
]

with open('employee-logins.csv', 'w') as file:
    for line in lines:
        file.write(line + '\n')

fields = []
rows = []


def readFile():
    with open('employee-logins.csv', 'r') as file:
        data = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
        fields[:] = next(data)
        for line in data:
            if (int(line[2]) >= 200):
                rows.append(line)


readFile()

print(fields)
print(rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using pandas DataFrames :

```py
import pandas as pd

# Read the csv into a DataFrame with a header :
df = pd.read_csv('employee-logins.csv')

# Filter only the rows with Logins>=200 ans save them into a new DataFrame: 
df_filtered = df[df.Logins>=200] 

# Transform back into string and then into list : 
final_list = df_filtered.astype("str").apply(lambda row: row.str.join(';'), axis=1).values.tolist()
```